# How to extract types from objects

Tags: typescript

I have a map:

```
const Map = {
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2'
}
```

I want to create a type `value1 | value2` using the above object. Is it possible without repeating the values?

I tried `type MyType = Map.key1 | Map.key2`, but it throws the following error:
`Cannot find namespace 'Map'`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First you have to declare the `MyMap` variable `as const`.

```
const MyMap = {
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2'
} as const
```

This tells typescript that the string literals in the object should be specific constants instead just inferred as `string`.

Now you can get the type of that object with the `typeof` keyword, then index that type by it's own keys to get all possible values:

```
type MyMapValues = typeof MyMap[keyof typeof MyMap] // "value1" | "value2"

const a: MyMapValues = "value1"
const b: MyMapValues = "value2"

// Error: Other values not allowed:
const c: MyMapValues = "value3"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?jsx=2#code/MYewdgzgLgBAsgTzgQwA4wLwwN4CgYwDWApggIwBcMA5AG7IA2ArsWdQDT5GkBMVdjFj2q4AvjGQQYoSFFy4oCVMXhI0ANUHEpWRcpAAzVSlQBtEgkMw9xK4hMBdGAHpnMAET1mrdzAA+Hl5C7vIy0BJU9hpaOoFaZCFhsABGkWqomt6xnlo8IbiuMACiAE4lICVUAPJQABbEJTBB2jBgILCMDCAA7sQAJhS4SdJpJpks2c0AzO5AA)

Answer (score 2):

```
const MyArray = [
    { name: "Alice", age: 15 },
    { name: "Bob", age: 23 },
    { name: "Eve", age: 38 }
];
type T = (typeof MyArray)[number];

const data = {
  value: 123,
  text: 'text',
  subData: {
    value: false
  }
};
type Data = typeof data;
```

Answer (score 2):

Indexing the map will only get the value, and not the actual type. Using this, you can get the type of the values

```
const myMap = {
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2'
}

type myType = typeof myMap["key1"] | typeof myMap["key1"]
```

Answer (score 1):

To make your keys as the type, they need to be fixed or defined or say `const`.

So, you can make the type as follows:

```
const Data = {
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2'
} as const;

type DataType = typeof Data[keyof typeof Data];
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=8&ssc=17&pln=8&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAIgQygmBeGBvAUDGBrAUwE8BGALhgHIA3BAGwFcCTKAaHfYgJgpvqa6UsAXxgIIMUJCgBuLFihEADgXhIEAFWWr0ilSABma5AG1CRQzD0FLiZAF05WOgVgIKdzdplA)